# How to get picture directly once we capture it? (Without usephoto/cancel step in the middle) (iOS 7)

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

Generally we use UIImagePickerDelegate to get the selected image from user. I need the image after the user captured it without asking usephoto/ cancel. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : Remove default camera controls by this method.

```
[pickerController setShowsCameraControls:NO];
```

Step 2 : Create an Overlay view and put one button on the overlay view to capture image.Set the view as picker controller's overlay view.

```
[pickerController setCameraOverlayView:camOverlay];
```

In the button action write this method:

```
[pickerController takePicture];
```

This automatically calls the delegate method and we will get the image directly with out use photo or cancel Step.

NOTE: Source type of picker controller should be camera to implement the above stuff.

```
pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

set delegate to self.